# Spring boot http response compression doesn't work for some User-Agents

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, compression, gzip

I'm trying to enable http response compression on Spring boot web application.
It works for some user-agents, and for some reason doesn't for others (specific cases below).

My basic question is:
**Why http response compression (gzip) in Spring Boot works only for some User-Agent headers and where it is configured.**

[Spring boot reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression) doesn't say anything about it.

I prepared simple web application with enabled compression: [sample spring-boot-compression app](https://github.com/szymonsobocik/spring-boot-compression)
There are integration tests that verify that gzip encoding works for some cases only.

I configured spring boot with:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    compression: on
    compressable-mime-types: text/html,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,application/font-sfnt,application/font-woff,application/font-woff2
```

When I try to do some requests with curl:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I see that `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is set.

When I set`User-Agent` to AppleWebKit (or some other browsers like IE) it does not compress:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -H "User-Agent: AppleWebKit" http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I repeated my tests with some other browsers and `User-Agent` header modification and received some strange results.

Here some of working (response is compressed) `User-Agent` headers:

```
- Mozilla/5.0
- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Firefox/34.0
- SomeUnknownBrowser
```

Some of **not** working `User-Agent` headers:

```
 - AppleWebKit
 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
 - Gecko/20100101
```

I also tried to use compression with `GzipFilter` and it behaves exactly the same. Also tried embedded Jetty instead of Tomcat - same result.

Maybe I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably using some sort of antivirus (maybe ESET). Try turning off HTTP protection.

With Eset you can try something like: Advanced -> Internet and email -> Web Access Protection - turn off.

Comment: Your answer is correct. The problem was not on a server side, but on my client machine (Windows 7 with ESET antivirus). It turned out, that response (checked with Wireshark) was being received gzipped, and somewhere between network interface na browser 'something' was unzipping it.

That 'something' was ESET.

Comment: ****** ESET! MF pointless "security" when accessing localhost addresses!

Comment: But what does it have to do with AppleWebKit? I can (unwillingly) accept that ESET is sticking its nose in, but just for AppleWebKit ?!!! Make no sense.

Comment: @ianbeks You're right, it would be weird. I think we would have to ask ssobocik if all of the tests were done solely on his machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Spring 1.4

```
 server.compression.enabled: true
server.compression.mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript
```