# Spring boot response compression not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have some javascript bundled file that is pretty big, ~1MB.
I'm trying to turn on response compression with the following application properties in my yml file:

```
server.compression.enabled: true
server.compression.mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
```

But it doesn't work. No compression is happening.

Request headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
```

Response headers

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:842821
Content-Type:application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
```

There's no content encoding header in the response.

I'm using spring boot version 1.3.5.RELEASE

What am I missing?

=== EDIT 4 ===
I was planning to create a stand alone app to investigate further why content compression properties weren't working.
But all of sudden it started working and I haven't changed any thing configuration-wise, not POM file change, not application.yml file change. So I don't know what has changed that made it working...

**===EDIT 3===**
follow @chimmi's suggestions further. I've put break points in the suggested places. It looks like requests to static resources (js files) never stopped at those break points. Only rest API requests do. And for those request, the content-length was zero for some reason which causes the content compression to be skipped.

[image]

**===EDIT 2===**
I've put a break point at line 180 of o.s.b.a.w.ServerProperties thanks to @chimmi's suggestion and it shows that all the properties are set but somehow the server doesn't honor the setting... :(

[image: Printing the Compression object at o.s.b.a.w.ServerProperties line 180]

**===EDIT 1===**

not sure if it matters, but I'm pasting my application main and configuration code here:

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TuangouApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TuangouApplication.class, args);
    }

    // this is for WAR file deployment
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TuangouApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class TuangouConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .headers().defaultsDisabled().cacheControl();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new DatabaseUserServiceDetails();
        }
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request
                        .getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null
                            || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Resource server config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this SO -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful

Comment: @aksappy yes i did. I based my solution on answer #2 from that link.

Comment: Your request headers have `keep-alive`, which indicate HTTP 1.0, but the referenced solution uses `AbstractHttp11Protocol `.  Maybe you need to be sending HTTP 1.1 requests?

Comment: What server are you using ? Tomcat ? Jetty ? ....

Comment: @benjamin.d  The code is deployed to AWS tomcat8

Comment: @heenenee The front end is written in Angular.js. Does it not send http 1.1 request? I'm not familiar with frond end stuff...

Comment: No, your browser will default to http 1.1 unless you have some strange configuration

Comment: Could you try to add a custom tomcat customizer, like described https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2031

Comment: If you look at response headers from http://stackoverflow.com/ do you see the gzip compression enabled ?

Comment: Are you sure you dont have *server.compression.min-response-size* set to something ridiculous somewhere?

Comment: You can verify actual properties you get at runtime by debugging line 180 at o.s.b.a.w.ServerProperties

Comment: Since all properties are in place I can only suggest more debugging. You can go from *TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.customizeCompression* to *AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureProcessor* and end up at *AbstractHttp11Processor* around line 1458

Comment: @chimmi It looks like request for static js files never reached `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.customizeCompression`. Only dynamic api result (application/json) stopped there. But compression was skipped because somehow contentLength was determined to be zero. see my screen shot update. Why would requests to static files bypass the mentioned code and why would content-length be zero for application/json response I returned? I used ResponseEntity.ok(obj) to build the API response.

Comment: @chimmi your suggestions took me the furthest. I can't award you the 50 points because you didn't create an answer. Could you please create an answer instead of commenting on my question directly so that I can give you 50 points? Thanks.

Comment: I will not do that since what i said is not an answer in any way. Instead let's try some more to tackle this thing. I tried to figure out where this 0 comes from, and it looks like there are two possibilities. 1. *java.io.File#length*  returns 0 when path is invalid. 2. Maybe some implementations of *java.net.URLConnection#getContentLength* can return 0 sometimes (there are a lot of them and i dont know which one is used). Please take a look at what is going on at *o.s.c.i.AbstractFileResolvingResource#contentLength*

Comment: Btw it is starting to feel like resources location misconfiguration.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the problem is with YAML configuration.
If you use ‘Starters’ SnakeYAML will be automatically provided via `spring-boot-starter`. If you don't - you must use properties convention in application.properties.
[Using YAML instead of Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml)

**EDIT:**
Try with this in your yml file:

```
server:
      compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript,application/json
        min-response-size: 1024
```

Comment: I tried the break point approach @chimmi suggested and it shows that all properties are read by spring boot container (I've updated my original post with the screenshot) but they are ignored somehow...

Answer (score 5):

Never had much luck with the Spring Boot compression.  A simple solution could be to use a third party library like ziplet.

Add to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ziplet</groupId>
    <artifactId>ziplet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Add to your @Config class :

```
@Bean
public Filter compressingFilter() {
    return new CompressingFilter();
}
```

Comment: why javax.servlet.servlet-api need to exclude ? if we exclude then What  will be package for Filter class ?

Comment: Spring already has a servlet library included, that's why you exclude this one.  Also this post is 4 years old, I'm sure compression in Spring Boot works properly now..

Comment: Ohh, Got it. Thanks. How we can provide configuration property to compressing filter? like change min response size,  mime type etc.. in ziplet readme mentioned config property but not mentioned example i.e how to add/configure

Comment: Look at this class for hints - you'll want to create a FilterConfig and pass it to the constructor of the CompressingServlet - https://github.com/ziplet/ziplet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/ziplet/filter/compression/CompressingFilterContext.java

Comment: Note from the future: Spring Boot compression still fails even on modern versions, so you may want to take a serious look at ziplet.

Answer (score 2):

If you use non-embedded Tomcat you should add this to your server.xml:

```
compression="on" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/javascript"
```

[More tomcat 8 config variables](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)

Comment: I guess he doesn't have a server.xml since he uses spring boot

Comment: I am having the same issue... I deploy my Spring Boot REST application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat instance), so there is no server.xml. Even though I specify `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`, I don't see a `Content-Encoding` in the response. How do I work around this?

Comment: my solution was Accept-Encoding on the request header Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6 I had to add the following to my `application.yml` to allow static resources to be compressed:

```
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      chain:
        compressed: true
```

The `server.compression` settings seem not to impact this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with different browsers? That could be because of antivirus which is unzipping the file as mentioned in the SO post [Spring boot http response compression doesn't work for some User-Agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563312/spring-boot-http-response-compression-doesnt-work-for-some-user-agents)

Comment: tried chrom, firefox, safari. all same behavior, no content compression. :(

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable ssl 
like http2 mode, response compression (Content-Encoding) can work, when ssl mode is configured.
[image: Content-Encoding:gzip]

### response compression

application.yml

```
server:
  compression:
     enabled: true
     mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
     min-response-size: 1024
  ssl:
   enabled: true
   key-store: keystore.p12
   key-store-password: pass
   keyStoreType: PKCS12
   keyAlias: name


spring:
  resources:   
      chain:
        gzipped: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on production. My configuration file is as follows:

```
server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
        min-response-size: 1024
```

Since i was not using the Embedded tomcat, I had to enable compression on the Tomcat itself by editing the following section of the `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" compression="on"/>
```

Make sure that this section has the `compression="on"` part and the issue should be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and spent many hours stepping through Apache and Spring code around this. I finally tracked it down to `org.apache.coyote.CompressionConfig::useCompression()` and found something surprising. If you're generating ETags and they're strong (that is, they don't start with W/) then compression is disabled.

I'm using Spring's `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter`, which. by default, generates strong ETags. My fix was to change that via `setWriteWeakETag(true)`.