# Setting Spring Boot property server.compression.enabled to true doesn't get applied to the autoconfigured Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, compression, gzip

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE and trying to get the internal Tomcat server to GZip the responses from the API I'm working on. As per the spring boot documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression adding `server.compression.enabled=true` to the application.properties should enable embedded web server's compression.

However the response I'm getting from the API doesn't look compressed.

[image: API response]

I've followed this question [Spring boot response compression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434834/spring-boot-response-compression-not-working) and when inspecting the ServerProperties's Compression object when application starts up, it looks like the enabled property is set to false.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Specify `mime-types` with compression like below.

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

Comment: Tried that with no success. As per the documentation those mime types are included in default mime-types.

Comment: @Kasum, which application server you are using in spring boot, it's by default (tomcat) or you changed?

Comment: it's the default tomcat sever

Comment: you need to configure that in Tomcat. Application server takes over. If you have apache server in front of Tomcat. need to enable it in Apache too

Answer (score 1):

Compression is disabled if strong Etag is enabled. I was using ShallowEtagHeaderFilter and as soon as I removed it, compression started working.